# iPhone scrollView add elements dynamically with id

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uiscrollview, element

I want to populate a scrollView with quite a few different UI elements. 
Therefore I thought I would write a method that remembers the current Position in the scrollView and just adds the element to the scrollView at the current Position.

Something like:

```
- (void)addUIElement:(id)element withWidth:(CGFloat)width andHeight:(CGFloat)height andYGap:(CGFloat)YGap {

    element.frame = CGRectMake(currentScrollPos.x, (currentScrollPos.y + YGap), width, height);
    [scrolly addSubview:element];

    //And then set the current scroll position here
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to do access element.frame = ..., I get request for member in something not a structure or union. When I try to do [element frame] = ... Lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

Now, first of all I am not sure what's the best way to dynamically add objects to a scrollview. Maybe anyone has a better or easier approach.

Then on the other hand, I don't get why the above does not work?! Would I have to cast my element to the actual class? I thought I would not have to do so... Also then my method would not make that much sense anymore. Or at least would require some more steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work I think:

```
 [element setFrame:...];
```

However if you work with different UI elements in your method may be you can make your elements parameter UIView* instead of id? This way your code will work for all UIView subclasses (which is what you actually need I suppose)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that already. But still. Somehow it should work with id... I will try setFrame though. Thanks

Comment: That actually worked. But I dont really get whats the difference? Compiler issue, or why does this work?

Comment: Yes it is compiler issue, having only id type compiler can't determine what frame is.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that "id" doesn't have any kind of reference to a frame. It could be *anything*. You want to instead do `(UIView *)element` in the method declaration, or alternatively in the call to element.frame, you would do `((UIView *)element).frame`.

(And yeah, all things that you put on the screen are inheriting from `UIView` -- `UIButton`, `UIImageView`, etc.)

Comment: Yeah I know that. I was just wondering why id did not work. Even though it does not have a reference I thought it should be checked at compile time...

Comment: "Compile time" has no clue what kind of stuff you'll end up throwing at an id-declared argument to a method -- you, or your coworker etc.